# ACF : How to add a new text field to Link field?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to add a new field to the already existing "Link" field in ACF.

This field would be a text field and used to output an ID on the front-end.

How can I do this with ACF ?

More generally, I'd like to add a text field to all Link Popup in my Wordpress backend.

Comment: Based on a support thread on the ACF forum, it doesn't sound like it's possible: [https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/add-new-input-field-to-acf-link/](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/add-new-input-field-to-acf-link/)